# Indiscrete topological space is regular and normal

Tags: general-topology

How to show that the indiscrete topological space X (where |X|>1)is regular and normal?

Comment: Did you try to apply the definition of a regular (respectively normal) space ?

Comment: Yes, but I am unable to separate a point and closed set for regular (respectively any two closed sets for normal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the wikipedia entry for [regular space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_space)

> A topological space $X$ is a *regular space* if, given any closed set $F$ and any point $x$ that does not belong to $F$, there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ and a neighbourhood $V$ of $F$ that are disjoint.

If the topology on $X$ is indiscrete, there are only two cases to consider: $F = \emptyset$ and $F = X$. In the first case, you can take $U = X$ and $V = F = \emptyset$. Then $x \in U$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$. In the latter case, there is no $x$ that does not belong to $F$ and the result is trivial.

The proof for normality is similar.

Comment: Now it's clear,Thanks sir.